# Unconfirmated bitcoin transaction, 1 day ago. Need Help

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

A friend have sent me money trough bitcoin. 
My transaction address is the next:https://blockchain.info/fr/tx/0e1d1862c344c6ea6c2036bdc85f1dd1a6e366b7ba1db2716d063b96d7290fb0

I don't understand why I have 0 confirmation. If someone can help I can send 10$ free. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your transaction will be confirmed soon. trust me :)

Comment: Your are the boss :) please send me your bitcoin address